# Entity Framework EDM.Binary Mapping to VB type

Tags: entity-framework, poco

I'm using POCOs with the latest version of EF 4.0 and have a timestamp field on my SQL Server 2008 db for handling optimistic concurrency.

The designer has created a mapping for the field with as an entity type of Binary. How should this be represented in my VB POCO as EDM.Binary is not available there? When I have the field as a Byte array, I get the error:

The type 'Edm.Binary' of the member 'RowVersionNr' in the conceptual side type 'SchoolModel.Course' does not match with the type 'System.Byte' of the member 'RowVersionNr' on the object side type 'EFLibrary.Course'.